# Game about rescuing books from churches

Tags: identify-this-game

I watched a review of this one a couple of years ago. It's set in France, I think, roughly late medieval / early Renaissance. There's religious unrest which is causing a lot of church burning, and you're trying to get the books to safety before they're burned up. It's a standard counters-on-a-board game.

Can anyone identify this?

Answer (score 2):

Could be Alexandria (although that's not exactly in France): https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/209538/alexandria

Comment: My thoughts exactly. It even came out around the same time as the OP saw the review